# Enable SSE encryption on DynamoDB table using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-dynamodb, terraform

I am trying to encrypt the DynamoDB table using Terraform. I added this block for SSE encryption:-

```
    server_side_encryption 
    {
    enabled = true
    kms_master_key_id = "${var.kmsid}"
    sse_algorithm     = "kms"
    }
```

But I am getting below error:

Error: aws_dynamodb_table.example: server_side_encryption.0: invalid or unknown key: kms_master_key_id
Error: aws_dynamodb_table.example: server_side_encryption.0: invalid or unknown key: sse_algorithm

Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: DynamoDB tables are always encrypted and its free. Thus there is nothing to enable. However, you can choose to use your own KMS key (not free). Do you have a requirement to use your own KMS key for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats not valid. Take a look [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/dynamodb_table.html#server_side_encryption-1) in the documentation.

The following should be specified:

- enabled
- kms_key_arn

Comment: Thank You mokugo-devops. The encryption worked for me.